# Is there any harm if the map directive in nginx is repeated for the same variable name?

Tags: nginx

When I try it out, the definition that comes later seems to take effect. The question is, are there unintended consequences of doing this?

```
http {
    map $http_host $a {
        hostnames;
        default 1;
        example.com 1;
        *.example.com 2;
    }
    map $http_host $a {
        hostnames;
        default 3;
        example.com 3;
        *.example.com 4;
    }
    server {
        server_name example.com *.example.com
        location / {
            echo $a
        }
    }
}
```

Now with this configuration if I try:

```
curl http://example.com
3
curl http://www.example.com
4
```

Background: We are using this to provide an override for a map in an optional include file. So right after the map is defined, we have an include directive for *_override_map.conf. If this file exists and provides an alternate definition for the same map, then thats what gets used instead of the original map definition.

Comment: I remember Nginx barfing at me once, because I had copy-pasted a block of config that included a map directive. So, unless I'm mistaken, it's probably an internal behaviour that depends on the particular version you are using. May I suggest asking on the Nginx mailing list?

Comment: Thanks Tobia. Good point about it being behavior in a particular version. I registered for the nginx mailing list. Waiting to activate it.